# Odd Even Sorting in VBA

Tags: vba, sorting

I am trying to sort rows of data so that the integer value of an alpha-numerical address is in order of odd values then even values given they are of the same type.

The only way I have got it to (semi)work was this:

-Find if the integer of the address is even or odd
-Add EVEN or ODD to a cell in that addresses corresponding row
-Run the macro
-Filter the data by EVEN or ODD designation

This approach isn't ideal. I am interested in rearranging the rows without having to use filtering.

Below is an example of how the sorting would go.

```
UNSORTED            SORTED  
Address Type        Address Type
1.1p    A           1.1p    A
1.2p    A           1.2p    A
1.3p    A           1.3p    A
1.4p    A           1.4p    A
2.1p    A           3.1p    A
2.2p    A           3.2p    A
2.3p    A           3.3p    A
2.4p    A           3.4p    A
3.1p    A           5.1p    A
3.2p    A           5.2p    A
3.3p    A           5.3p    A
3.4p    A           5.4p    A
4.1p    A           2.1p    A
4.2p    A           2.2p    A
4.3p    A           2.3p    A
4.4p    A           2.4p    A
5.1p    A           4.1p    A
5.2p    A           4.2p    A
5.3p    A           4.3p    A
5.4p    A           4.4p    A
6.1p    B           7.1p    B
6.2p    B           7.2p    B
6.3p    B           7.3p    B
6.4p    B           7.4p    B
7.1p    B           9.1p    B
7.2p    B           9.2p    B
7.3p    B           9.3p    B
7.4p    B           9.4p    B
8.1p    B           6.1p    B
8.2p    B           6.2p    B
8.3p    B           6.3p    B
8.4p    B           6.4p    B
9.1p    B           8.1p    B
9.2p    B           8.2p    B
9.3p    B           8.3p    B
9.4p    B           8.4p    B
10.1p   B           10.1p   B
10.2p   B           10.2p   B
10.3p   B           10.3p   B
10.4p   B           10.4p   B
```

I am new to VBA. Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: You need to give us more specifics. What data structure / format is the data stored in. Let us see your code, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a helper column where you can store a value that you can use for sorting.

Basic idea is to extract the numeric value from your "Adress" column, check if it is even and if yes multiply it by an high value (eg 1000) so that it is guaranteed to be higher than the highest possible odd value.

You can use either a **formula** for this cell - but it's looking a little complicated to me. Assuming that your data starts in cell A2:

```
=VALUE(LEFT(A2, SEARCH("p", A2, 1)-1))*IF(ISODD(VALUE(LEFT(A2, SEARCH("p", A2, 1)-1))),1,1000)
```

or write a small **UDF**

```
Function SortVal(s As String) As Double
    SortVal = Val(s)
    If Int(SortVal) Mod 2 = 0 Then SortVal = SortVal * 1000
End Function
```

and put a call to it in your helper column

```
=SortVal(A2)
```